# How to use File Tranform for an endpoint in DevOps

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I'm transforming my Web.config in my Release Pipeline in Azure DevOps.
In this Web.config I have multiple AppSettings keys, but I also have one Endpoint.

I also want to make the address of this endpoint to be a variable from Azure DevOps.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for Variable transformation for which you can do the following

- Create a release pipeline with a stage named Release.
- Add an Azure App Service Deploy task and set (tick) the XML variable substitution option.

[image]

- Define the required values in release pipeline variables:

[image]

- Save the release pipeline and start a new release.
- Open the Web.config file to see the variable substitutions.
- By default, ASP.NET applications have a default parameterized connection attribute. These values are overridden only in the parameters.xml file inside the web package.
- Because substitution occurs before deployment, the user can override the values in Web.config using parameters.xml (inside the web package) or a setparameters file.

You can also refer this link for reference.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2018/03/19/manage-web-config-values-between-environments-in-release-management-and-tfs/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops

Hope it helps.